# Why is "delight" spelt and pronounced the way it is?

Tags: etymology, nouns, pronunciation, orthography

This as everything probably has something to do with the GVS, but how?

Comment: The V in GVS stands for Vowel, so no consonants need apply.

Comment: Where *GVS* is the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) presumably?

Answer (score 10):

It is spelled that way because of an error that stuck around.

What dictionary did you consult that failed to explain this?  Please tell us, so that we can steer people clear of it in the future.

The OED says of *delight* the noun:

> ME. *delit*, a. OFr. *delit* (-*eit*), (= Pr. *deliet*, Sp. *deleite*, Ital. diletto), f. stem of *deliter* vb. 
> The etymological *delite* is found as late as 1590, but earlier in 16th c. it had generally been supplanted by *delight*, an erroneous spelling after *light*, *flight*, etc.

And it says this of *delight* the verb:

> ME. *delite-n*, a. OFr. *delitier* (*-leitier, -leter, -liter*) = Pr., Sp. *delectar*, Sp., Pg. *deleitar*, Ital. *delettare*, *dilettare*:-L. *dēlectāre* to allure, attract, delight, charm, please, freq. of *dēlicĕre* to entice away, allure: cf. **delicious**. 
> The current erroneous spelling after *light*, etc. arose in the 16th c., and prevailed about 1575: the Bible of 1611 occasionally retained *delite*.

The oldest noun uses of *delight* are:

> - A. 1225 *Ancr. R.* 272 ― So sone so me··let þene lust gon inward & delit waxen.
> - A. 1225 *Ancr. R.* 102 ― Þes cos··is a swetnesse & a delit of heorte.
> - C. 1230 *Hali Meid.* 7 ― And habbeð mare delit þerin þen anie oðre habbeð i likinge of þe worlde.
> - A. 1240 *Ureisun* in *Cott. Hom.* 201 ― Þe muchele delit of þine swetnesse.
> - A. 1300 *Cursor M.* 23339 (Cott.) ― Bot suld þai haf a gret delite, To se þam setlid in þair site.
> - C. 1340 *Cursor M.* 8164 (Fairf.) ― Þai hailsed him wiþ grete delite.
> - C. 1385 Chaucer *L.G.W.* 1199 *Dido*, ― With sadyl red enbroudit with delyt.
> - C. 1386 Chaucer *Prol*. 335 ― To lyuen in delit was euere his wone, For he was Epicurus owene sone.

While the oldest verb uses are:

> - A. 1225 *Ancr. R.* 52 ― Eue··iseih hine ueir, & ueng to deliten i þe biholdunge.
> - C. 1300 *K. Alis.* 5802 ― So hy ben delited in that art That wery ne ben hy neuere cert.
> - 1303 R. Brunne *Handl. Synne* 3086 ― Ȝyf þou delyte þe oftyn stoundes, Yn horsys, haukys, or yn houndes.
> - A. 1325 *Prose Psalter* l[i]. 17 ― Þou ne shalt nouȝt deliten in sacrifices.
> - C. 1340 *Cursor M.* 1560 (Fairf.) ― A-mong caymys kyn, þat delitet ham al to syn.
> - C. 1374 Chaucer *Anel. & Arc.* 266 ― But for I··was so besy you to delyte.
> - C. 1385 Chaucer *L.G.W.* 415 ― Yet hath he made lewde folke delyte To serue yow.

Even Chaucer back in the 14<sup>th</sup> century varied his spelling of the word, alternating between using a *y* or an *i*, and whether to use a final vowel.  By the time the 16<sup>th</sup> century rolled around, the word we now spell as *light* had many spellings, including in particular *lyte*.  It is quite likely that *delight* was caught up in that same spelling change.

As for the pronunciation, I am not sure what you would be expecting there. It is not a new import from Latin like *infect* is, having gone through Old French and lost its *-c-*.  I can’t think of many English words that sound like that but which came from a Latin *-ect-*, but with *despite* and *indict* being two possible examples.  Things like *incite* and *recite* never had the *-ct-*.

Parallel, perhaps, to *delight* is the legal term, *delict*, from Latin *dēlictum*.  It is pronounced /dɪˈlɪkt/, and originated in the 16<sup>th</sup> century.  It is perhaps most commonly seen in the phrase *in flagrant delict*, which is  translated either from the Latin *in flagrante delicto* or from the French, *en flagrant délit*.

Comment: _Delite_ is widely used in trade names and informal spelings. Fixed spelling is an archaic restriction imposed by the orthographic technology of printing. Before Caxton, spelling was as individual as handwriting. Now that printing has been transformed, spelling has no use and is being largely abandoned, like cursive writing and the long ſ.

Comment: @JohnLawler What does “spelling has no use” mean?

Comment: It means that most people don't spell consistently, and this is no longer a problem, now that more and more people read cooperatively, since they, along with search engines and writing software, can figure it out, whether it's spelt the way they expect or not. Technology changes, a fact that applies to all technology, including literacy.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It is not so simple. Uniform spelling has various advantages, some of which have only become more important in the digital age. For one thing, people read a text for a significant part based on the shape of a word, not letter by letter, and varying spelling can change this shape radically. It is easier and quicker if the same word always has the same shape—although of course a certain degree of flexibility is not necessarily a problem. Secondly, digital search engines are often not very good ad handling spelling variants, especially incidental, accidental, and new ones.

Comment: Perhaps. And perhaps not. Time will tell, as it always has.